# How do you split a user-inputted string by the white space

Tags: clojure

I have made a temperature type in which a user should be able to enter a temperature in Celsius, Fahrenheit, or Kelvin. I am making a function that given an input such as "100 F" it will split the string, and create a temperature with degrees 100 & scale F. I need to be able to split it by the white space so I can pass them into my constructor to make the type. I am currently doing it by using subs but overlooked that if I pass a larger number it would not split it correctly. Is there a way to split by a space, or white space in user input.

I have to use a picture as I am logging in virtually to a machine and cannot copy paste.

[image: Code here]

I need them to be able to enter anywhere from absolute zero of the respective temperature to as high as they want it to be, for example 1000 F.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. You can put your code in the question itself and now it's copy- and search-able for everyone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split a string, you should use `clojure.string/split`. Great examples here:
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split

Comment: When I put in that code, and try and create a vector of the 2 parts. I get an Arity Exception: Wrong number of args (1) passed. I did it like this `temp [(clojure.string/split userInput])` and userInput is the input put into that variable.

Comment: An "Arity Exception" means that you're calling the function with the wrong number of argument. The `clojure.string/split` function takes 2 arguments: the string to split and the separator. So in your case you should use `(clojure.string/split userInput #" ")`.
You should lean the basics of clojure and make some challenge at http://www.4clojure.com/